# defining .style.height in javascript not working with canvas image

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and for some reason, that I cannot figure out, it isn't working. I have tried both:
    `image.style.height = '10px';` and      `image.height = '10px';`

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var image = new Image();
image.src = "http://pngimg.com/upload/horse_PNG2523.png";
image.style.height = '10px';
image.style.width = '20px';
```

Comment: Read about `canvasContext.drawImage`

Comment: @rayon ok, cool, it works differently

Comment: When you talk about `Canvas`, `Element.style.*` is out of consideration...